# Calculating variance with "- - -" values

Tags: tibco, spotfire

hoping you can help me calculate a variance which contains a "- - -" value. In short, I have 1 large XLS data source which contains 2 months of data (month is defined by a specific column) and I am trying to calculate the variance between parts sold to various customers, from Month 1 to Month 2. However, one of the parts is brand new for Month 2 - so when I calculate the variance at the Customer level everything looks fine, but when I drill to the part level there is "blank" variance because Month 1 contained no data. I would really like it to show as a positive variance (ie: if the part was 0 and is now 10, I would like it to show 10).

I have tried the SN function and investigating pivoting, but am currently completely stuck!

Thanks!

Comment: Where does `---` come from? Can you replace it with zero `0`?

Comment: Hi Dan. When I create a Cross Table with Customer/Part on the Y and Month on the X the - - - appears in Month 1 for the new part which only has data for Month 2. When I then try to calculate the variance between the months it simply reports as a blank cell.

Comment: @Grant can you post some sample data?

Comment: @Dan `---` is similar to `NULL` for display purposes but it doesn't have to be row based, it can be "missing" entirely so replacing won't always work unless there is an explicit row for each instance.

Comment: Grant did you figure this out?

Comment: If you're still trying to solve this, it might help to specify what equation you're using to determine variance.
Based on your description, I would do something along the lines of `Sum(if([Month] = 2, [PartsSold], 0)) - Sum(if([Month] = 1, [PartsSold], 0)) as Variance` which keeps both months in the dataset so you won't run into the blank problem.